How to Use extracted JSON array data in loop in JMeter?
I have a workflow where user can create tickets using equipment numbers.
Now from API response I'm getting equipment numbers. So using JSON extractor to store those in variable "equipmentNumber", with "match no. -1" (so getting all the equipment numbers which are present in response lets say 10 numbers)
Now in next post request if is use variable "${equipmentNumber_1}" then first value from response gets passed.
But I want to run this post request 10 times and use all equipmentNumber values in loop, which I am getting like equipmentNumber_1, equipmentNumber_2, equipmentNumber_3...till 10. So how to achieve that ?
[JSON Extractor](httpsenter image description here://i.sstatic.net/wZ858ZY8.png)

If you add a Debug Sampler or PostProcessor after the JSON Extractor you will see the following variables defined:
equipmentNumber_1=foo
equipmentNumber_2=bar
equipmentNumber_3=baz
equipmentNumber_matchNr=3

In order to loop through them add a ForEach Controller and configure it like this:

Ądd your POST request as a child of the ForEach Controller and it will iterate as many times as there are matches in your JsonPath expression
